# How to Get the cities of the world?

Tags: php

**Hello
I have a site and want to add all the cities of the world by country
Where can I file has an all cities?**

thanks

000000

Comment: You can find your answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/2384012/2025771

Comment: Have a look at: http://www.geonames.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display the Country and cities dropdown, you need to have database tables for this with all country and cities.

You can get this database from here: 
https://www.maxmind.com/en/free-world-cities-database